# Solr Ngram Match Woe

Tags: search, solr, lucene, full-text-search

This is my (pretty standard) ngram schema --

```
<fieldType name="ngram" class="solr.TextField" positionIncrementGap="100" stored="false" multiValued="true">
  <analyzer type="index">
    <tokenizer class="solr.StandardTokenizerFactory"/>
    <filter class="solr.LowerCaseFilterFactory"/>
    <filter class="solr.NGramFilterFactory" minGramSize="1" maxGramSize="15"/>
  </analyzer>
  <analyzer type="query">
    <tokenizer class="solr.StandardTokenizerFactory"/>
    <filter class="solr.LowerCaseFilterFactory"/>
  </analyzer>
</fieldType>
```

now laptop_ngram:"g74sx-a" returns --

```
<arr name="laptop_ngram">
  <str>ASUS G74SX-A1 17.3-Inch Gaming Laptop</str>
</arr>
```

but laptop_ngram:"g74sx-a1" finds nothing.

BTW, escaping the "-" does not make any difference.

Any thought?

Comment: any reason why not using the same analyzer set for the query too?

Comment: You mean add solr.NGramFilterFactory to query analyzer?

Comment: yes (I need to put 12 characters....)

Answer (score 1):

The StandardTokenizerFactory might do something to the term. You can check this in the analysis page.

So changing to WhitespaceTokenizerFactory could fix the problem.

Comment: I tried WhitespaceTokenizerFactory, unfortunately the result is not great, meaning it finds "g74sx a1", but not when the canonical production model "g74sx-a1" is fed. Thanks to your pointer, it showed me new direction that I went back searching. It seems WordDelimiterFilterFactory could help, but it's been half an hour and I haven't figured out how to find/download/compile/add that class for my Solr 3.4 :(

Comment: You don't need to download it. Just add it to your schema. Read http://wiki.apache.org/solr/AnalyzersTokenizersTokenFilters#solr.WordDelimiterFilterFactory for more information.

Answer (score 1):

Thanks to O. Klein, who showed me new direction.

I finally settle with WhitespaceTokenizerFactory plus WordDelimiterFilterFactory --

```
<fieldType name="ngram" class="solr.TextField" positionIncrementGap="100" stored="false" multiValued="true">
  <analyzer type="index">
    <tokenizer class="solr.WhitespaceTokenizerFactory"/>
    <filter class="solr.WordDelimiterFilterFactory" generateWordParts="1" generateNumberParts="1" catenateWords="1" catenateNumbers="1" catenateAll="1" preserveOriginal="1"/>
    <filter class="solr.LowerCaseFilterFactory"/>
    <filter class="solr.NGramFilterFactory" minGramSize="1" maxGramSize="15"/>
  </analyzer>
  <analyzer type="query">
    <tokenizer class="solr.WhitespaceTokenizerFactory"/>
    <filter class="solr.LowerCaseFilterFactory"/>
  </analyzer>
</fieldType>
```

which works for "g74sx", "g74sx-", "g74sx-a", and "g74sx-a1"

However, the journey didn't end here, as I'm still exploring why --

"G74SX-XA1" is found with "g74sx-x" and "g74sx-xa1", but not "g74sx-xa"...